# windows phone check box database checked value(?)

Tags: windows-phone-7, checkbox

I have 200 checkbox on my app and I have to change their ischecked values. so I want to usem the code lıke that:

checkbox(i).ischecked=true;(it is not working:) )

is this possible? or how can I use codes for it with c#? I think you understood me already.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
        string a = "image2";   
        Image ima = this.FindName(a) as Image;
        ima.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        string b = "checkBox1";
        CheckBox ch = this.FindName(b) as CheckBox;
        ch.IsChecked = true;
```